# Hidden "Icon" file not hidden in OS X Dock folder

Tags: macos, dock

In OS X Yosemite, I have the Desktop folder pinned to my Dock. Since Google Drive is installed and pointed at my Desktop folder, the Desktop folder has a persistent "Icon" file that I can't delete, due to the Google Drive's custom icon.

This is fine, I don't mind the icon one way or the other, but the problem is that this hidden "Icon" file (which is hidden in the Finder) is not hidden in the Dock's folder view. Whether I have the folder set to display as a Fan, Grid or List, this "Icon" file is still visible.

It's worth noting that the Dock has no problem keeping the hidden dot files hidden (".DS_Store" and ".localized") -- it's just the "Icon" file that annoyingly appears.

How can I hide or remove this file from the Dock's folder view?

Comment: 9 years later, this problem persists!